# How to set the correct time in cliniko API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging, momentjs

I am trying to make a booking platform. I am facing an issue that when i send the request into cliniko's API, My time is getting reserved at a slot which is 4 hours behind the slot i send the request for. Here is my code to make the request

```
app.post('/makeBooking', (req, res) => {

  console.log('===========old=======start date: ',req.body.startDate)
  console.log('===========new=======end date: ',req.body.endDate)

  let newStartDate = moment.utc(req.body.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ')
  let newEndDate = moment.utc(req.body.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ')


   console.log('===========old=======start date: ',newStartDate)
  console.log('===========new=======end date: ', newEndDate)

  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "starts_at": newStartDate,
    "ends_at": newEndDate,
    "notes": req.body.note,
    "business_id": "436798402274003408",
    "practitioner_id": "436798398809508395",
    "patient_id": "6",
    "appointment_type_id": "436798401980402014"
  });

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      return res.status(200).json({ error: false, message: 'Success', data: response.data })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
       console.log('==================================',error.response);
      console.log(error);
    });
})
```

i am not sure if converting it into utc is the right thing to do. My time zone is EST.

Comment: Appears to be a time zone issue. What zone is the API server in? Is it expecting UTC times?

Comment: @DrewReese yes it is expecting time in utc. But i am already converting it to utc.

Comment: Have you confirmed your actual outgoing request has datetimes in UTC? Confirmed there is no time offset still hanging around? Do you have access to the endpoint to confirm it doesn't do any data mangling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by converting the time zone like this

`let newStartDate = moment(req.body.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').utc().format()`

`let newEndDate = moment(req.body.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').utc().format()`

Instead of doing this

`let newStartDate = moment.utc(req.body.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')`